# How can I read chrome Login Data file?

Tags: c#, sqlite, google-chrome

I wanted to read Google chrom's passwords. My current approach:

```
string google = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History";
string fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
File.Copy(google, Application.StartupPath + "\\" + fileName);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource = " + Application.StartupPath + "\\" + fileName + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");

con.Open();
//SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select url,title,visit_count,last_visit_time from urls order by last_visit_time desc", con);
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from urls order by last_visit_time desc", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
con.Close();

try // File already open error is skipped
{
    if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + fileName))
    {
        File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + fileName);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

But it throws:

> Data Source cannot be empty. Use :memory: to open an in-memory
>   database

How should I handle that error?

Comment: Why would passwords be stored in the history file? Do you mean URLs? I would also remove the space after `"DataSource = "`

Comment: You could try something like this http://pastebin.com/DdDM8dpN